# Beginner's question !! DSolve for EulerEquation, can't interpret answer

Tags: equation-solving

Hi I just need help understanding this short solution I got for my physics problem set, I couldnt find an explanation in the documentation so I got desperate and am trying to ask here. Thanks! I just need an explanation for what I got, not an answer to the question, problem attached for context only. Any help is appreciated!

[image: I made this short snippet of code for some physics problem set. I'm supposed to find the transcendental equation that a satisfies, and then sketch it. I just need to know what the periods (".") in the solution i got mean. Any help is appreciated!]

[image: This is the problem concerned. I'm not asking for answers! Just need help interpreting the "." I got in my equation, I couldn't find it in the documentation either]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post your code, not an image.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqn = EulerEquations[(1/c) 3/2 E^(-a y[x]) (1 + y[x]^2)^(1/2), y[x], x]

(* -((3 E^(-a y[x]) (a - y[x] + a y[x]^2))/(2 c Sqrt[1 + y[x]^2])) == 0 *)

sol = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x]

(* {{y[x] -> (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 a^2])/(2 a)}, {y[x] -> (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a^2])/(2 a)}} *)
```

The output of [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) indicates that there are two solutions (expressed as a replacement [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)) either of which satisfy the equation. Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

However, since the equation is **not** a differential equation. [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) would work just as well.

```
sol2 = Solve[eqn, y[x]]

(* {{y[x] -> (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 a^2])/(2 a)}, {y[x] -> (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 a^2])/(2 a)}} *)
```

The solutions from `DSolve` and `Solve` are identical ([`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html))

```
sol2 === sol

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much !!

Comment: @IanAngeloAragoza if you’ve found this answer to your liking, click the ✔️ and turn it green to accept the answer :) it would also be better for future users if you updated your question with the code in your picture instead of just having the image. Great answer, Bob!